# Как из строки получить массив символов

Tags: javascript

Есть строка:

```
var s = "строка";
```

Нужно получить из этой строки массив символов:

```
'с' 'т' 'р' 'о' 'к' 'а'
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: а зачем получать именно массив?

Comment: для доступа по индексу строку не надо переводить в массив - она и так позволяет обращаться к конкретному символу

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Метод split() разбивает строку по указанному селектору

```js
var s = "строка",
    //Укажем пустую строку чтобы разбить по символам
    arr = s.split('');
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 6):

В ES2015 можно [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
console.log(Array.from("строка"))
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно через RegExp:

```js
var s = "строка",
    arr = s.match(/./g);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один способ с помощью [оператора spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
console.log([...'строка'])
```